# How can you extend a motion in an image with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, cs5

I have extended an image: [image: Extended Image (Close View)]

Now when zooming out it is like this: [image: Extended Image (Far View)]

It is clearly visible that the extend part wasn't part of the picture.  Do you have any clue how I can fix this?  I'm just trying to let the image look like it has never been extended, so remove of the line and such in the middle.  How can I do this in Photoshop?  I'm not sure what terms to google for.

Comment: Use content aware scaling - there's a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hUC1HR8RWY)

Comment: I did exactly that @Billy Kerr, but that results in the image being incorrectly resized. So I just selected the blank area on the right and did a "New Layer via Copy" and then pasted it into the blank area. 
So the attached piece does not align properly with the image's escape point because it has been moved. So I guess I just need to tilt the image. Edit >> Transform >> Perspective

Or do you have any other idea?

Comment: That's odd, I just tried content aware scaling, and the result is pretty good.  [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/aJZO2Ha)

Comment: The go to feature for stuff like this is **`Filter > Vanishing Point...`**. You draw in the perspective grid(s) and then either paste in images or use the clone stamp tool.

Comment: The easiest way to do this form where you are is marquee select the are that is bad (and a bit over). HIt shift backspace, and chose content aware and hit done. And you get the same as  mayersdesign without any masking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been playing around with Content Aware Scale after being inspired by this question, and have what I think is a great solution, quite different from my first, and an awful lot easier! A one minute solution.

1. Draw a rough selection around the car, I simply used the Polygonal Lasso
2. In the Channels palette click the "Save selection as channel" button
3. Hit "Edit" > "Content-Aware Scale"
4. On the top bar, under "Protect" select the Alpha channel (Alpha 1)
5. Drag the handle to scale the image, noting that the car is not distorted at all.

I was very pleased to extend my knowledge of content aware scaling, and I think the result is basically flawless:

[image]

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the bounty, much appreciated :)

Comment: Deserved. This is an awesome technique.

Answer (score 4):

The image here is by **no means perfect**, but I can tell you how I achieved it in two or three minutes, and hopefully you can use my notes as a guide to get it right (in half an hour+ haha):

1. Create new layer using as much of the land to the right of the car
   as you can get
2. Delete the equal portion from the main image
3. Move the new section of land under the main image, move it to the
   right so that it fills the gap (currently looks terrible)
4. Use a combination of content aware scaling, persepctive transform
   and regular transform to shape it to fit..so that the rails line up
   (tricky)
5. I never could get the lower rail and the top rail correct at the
   same time, so in the end I made a new layer, and put a small section
   of green along the top rail to line it up.
6. The key part, apply a layer mask to the main image and gradient
   blend the two layers together, then a bunch (and it would take a
   bunch more to finish it) hand adjust with mask blending, cloning,
   dodging - all of it! haha. The sky to the upper right is particularly tricky. I might think about replacing that entire section with sky from elsewhere in the image.

Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. I would do it in a partial way. So, first of all, let's copy upper part of our picture and bring it to the right of our workspace, but remember to put the part of an image on the original (as you can see on the picture). Also, we have to to fit the "lines" of our copy part and the background.
   [image]
2. Same story for the lower part.
   [image]
3. Now switch to the upper copied layer, take the eraser tool with small soft brush and delicate erase left edge of copied picture. You should see then something like on the picture below.
   [image]
4. Same story for the lower part. I'm not that good with Photoshop, but you can improve the effect by Clone Stamp Tool, or Smudge Tool if you like.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Flip a copied slice horizontally and apply vertical skew. The seam has no color jump because the extension is the original mirrored. Also there's nothing remarkably stretched horizontally nor bendings on the road surface details.

[image]

Fade some detail with cloning to hide it's mirrored. You can also add an adjustment layer which have gradient layer mask.

Here some cloning is applied and the railing has got brightness adjustment. The layers were merged to keep things simple:

[image]

Comment: I like the mirroring approach. Any of these solutions could work of course, it just depends on the image, and how much of  hole there is to fill!